# Why does the max principle stress at yielding for a ductile material equal to its yield strength in a uniaxial tensile test?

Tags: structural-analysis, failure-analysis

It is thought that the maximum principal stress for a ductile material is equal to its yield strength, in a uniaxial tensile test. This is also shown in the attached picture. I want to ask why is this the case? I mean why not is max shear stress at yielding equal to the yield strength of the material?

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkbQnBAOFEg&t=14s&ab_channel=TheEfficientEngineer

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is.

When a material is loaded the stress state in the material is the same - it does not depend on the orientation that the stresses are analysed.

Mohr's circle is a way of visualising a stress state at different orientations/planes.

At yielding of the material, the **stress state** is  that the maximum shear strength at yielding is equal to the shear stress in the 45 degree plane.

The **same** *stress state* at the plane which is parallel to the uniaxial tensile load, is equal to the tensile yield stress.

Answer (score 0):

Your graph tells a different story.

[image]

From the property of the Mohr's Circle,

$\tau_{max} = \dfrac {\sigma_1 - \sigma_2}{2}$

For $\sigma_2 = 0$, (uniaxial loading)

$\sigma_1 = 2\tau_{max}$, or as indicated in the graph, $\sigma_y = 2\tau_y$

In which, $\sigma_1$ is the tensile stress. Does this answer your question?